# openpyxl reading column width from a .xlsx and writing it to a new .xlsx: width is different in a new file

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I am using openpyxl to work with `.xlsx` files in `Python`.

I have a `sample.xlsx` file from which I want to get a list of title fields and column width to use in the file generated by my script.

At first I create a list with column names and their corresponding widths.
So I use:

```
filter_list = {"name": [], "width": []} 
row_count = sheet.max_row 
   for i in range(row_count): 
      cell = sheet.cell(row, i + 1) 
      if cell.value: 
        filter_list["name"].append(cell.value)
        filter_list["width"].append(sheet.column_dimensions
             [cell.column].width)
```

value to get column widths and then I set the same value:

```
if filter_list["width"][i] is not None: 
    sheet.column_dimensions[cell.column].width = filter_list["width"][i]
```

It works fine if a particular column has a non-default value (i.e. not None). When I open the output file (on both Mac and Windows) I see that the width of this particular column is the same for both files.

But if one of the columns has ...width = `None` in the input file (so the output file have the same `None` value for column width parameter) the same column in the output file looks different.

Any ideas on why it happens?

It looks like somewhere in the `.xlsx` there is a parameter, which somehow defines what the default width (= None value) is set to.

Is there any way to make both files look the same in terms of column width?

**Update:** I added a check for width value of `None`. I only set the column width parameter for columns that have not `None` value. The result is still the same - files are different in terms for default width.

**Update 2:** I have updated the code to show exactly how I read and set column width.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the first bit: No, no idea why it happens

But in answer to the second, it seems to me to be as straightforward as:

```
if mywidth is not None:
    output_sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = mywidth
```

ie in a loop through all the columns just check that the column width is actually defined. If it is then apply it to the new sheet, if not then just ignore it.

NB it's `column_dimensions` (plural) not the singular version

**EDIT** After question updates:

The way that Excel deals with default column widths is on a worksheet level. Having looked at a couple of basic Excel workbooks using the [OpenXML tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) then cross referencing with the [openpyxl docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/dimensions.html#SheetFormatProperties) it would seem that you might be after the following:

```
wb1 = load_workbook("my/workbook/name.xlsx")
ws1 = wb1.active
default_col_width = ws1.sheet_format.defaultColWidth
```

Alternatively, once you've opened the new workbook go to the `Home` tab, `Cells` section, click the `Format` button and choose `Default width...` and set it as you want.

Comment: As for your proposal - unfortunately that doesn't help. I do check that column width of a particular column is not None and then set the value. But the resulting file is still has a different default column width.

Comment: Perhaps worksheet.sheet_format.defaultColWidth will help. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, shunty! It helps in a way that when I set a width for a new sheet it changes the default. But, for some reason, I still can't get the same width for both .xlsx, although I read and write sheet_format.defaultColWidth.

Answer (score 1):

If a column dimension has a width of `None`, Excel defaults to `0` and not to the default column width for the worksheet. openpyxl tries to make it easy to access dimensions by creating them if they do not exist. So your code is creating some with `width=None` in both files, but the effect of this only becomes visible when you save the file.

In your case you should be able to avoid problems by working explicitly with the dimensions in the first file:

```
for k, cd in ws1.column_dimensions.items():
    ws2.column_dimensions[k].width = cd.width
```

Comment: I am checking that value of the column width I red from the input file is not None and only record an existing non None values to the output file. But the result is what  I have explained.

Comment: That is not obvious from the code you have provided. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: Reading: `filter_list = {"name": [], "width": []}
    row_count = sheet.max_row
    for i in range(row_count):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, i + 1)
        if cell.value:
            filter_list["name"].append(cell.value)
            filter_list["width"].append(sheet.column_dimensions[cell.column].width)` 
 Writing: `if filter_list["width"][i] is not None:
   sheet.column_dimensions[cell.column].width = filter_list["width"][i]`

Comment: So, I only write the value if it's not None

Comment: Please update the code in the original question where it's easier to read.

Comment: Updated! Thank you for your help

Comment: Ok, use `column_dimensions.get(cell.column)` to check whether there is a CD for the relevant column. You only need to copy the width if there is.

Comment: OK, right now I read value None from those fields with no width set. And I don't write them to a new file. But I will optimise code to make this check.